# get nested array lengths in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the following array layout :

```
var indicators = 
{
    items:
    {
        array1:[],
        array2:[]
    }       
};
```

and I have the following handlebars code to make a template :

```
var source =
    '{{#items}}' +
        '<div class="listItem" onclick="clickListItem({{@index}});">' +
        '<div class="leftSide">' +
        '<div class="listTitle"> {{SOMETHING MUST GO HERE, RIGHT?}} </div>' + 
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '{{/items}}';

var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$('.list').html(template(indicators));
```

As you can probably see here - I want to create a list that will appear on screen, which simply displays the length of each array inside indicators (array1, and array2) - How do I get that data for each array - The code I have does iterate over indicators.items, but how do I get the length of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?. to get the data for each array inside your `items` object

```
{{#items}}
   {{#array1}}
   {{/array1}}

   {{#array2}}
   {{/array2}}
{{/items}}
```

can you try this?.. it gets the array lengths inside your items object

```
var arrayLengths = [];
var objects = { 
  array1: [1,2,3,4,5,12,55],
  array2: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  array3: [1,2,3,4,5,3,4],
  array4: [1,2,3,4,5,10,23],
  array5: [1,2,3,4,5,440,120]
};
for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key].length;
    arrayLengths.push(value);
}
console.log(arrayLength);
```

Comment: Thanks - but this isn't exactly what I need, what I want is the length of array1 and array2 - not the elements. Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: {{array1.length}} {{array2.length}} ?

Comment: That would work - but then my UI would be hardcoded, where as I need this to be able to work for N nested arrays inside "items" - like, in the code above I only have array1, and array2, but at run time, it is entirely plausible that I might end up with 10 or 11 arrays inside "items".

Comment: does the `items` object will consists of arrays only?

Comment: I edited my comment a while ago.. it gets the array lengths inside your `items` object

Comment: Thanks :) This is more like what I was after.

Comment: By any chance would you know the answer to my other question also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389756/send-array-to-function-in-handlebars?noredirect=1#comment56521279_34389756

Comment: I proposed an answer. maybe you can check if it fits your needs.