# Send array to function in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the following piece of code...

```
 var mainArray = 
{
    nestedArrays:
    {
        array1:[... items ...],
        array2:[... items ...]
    }
};

var source =
    '{{#nestedArrays}}' +
        '{{#each this}}' +
            '<div class="listItem" onclick="populateSecondMenu({{SEND THIS ARRAY!}});">' +
                '<div class="leftSide">' +
                    '<div class="listTitle">Indicator : {{this.length}} </div>' + 
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '{{/each}}' +          
        '{{/items}}';

var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$('.list').html(template(mainArray));
```

As you can already see here, I am able to iterate over this structure, and place the length of both "array1" and "array2" inside list items on the UI.

However, What I also want to be able to do - is to be able to pass the current item to a the function when inside the "#each" tags - see that function call, "populateSecondMenu"? I want to put the array I am at now - so that I can pass that in, How might I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to have a stringy way of finding that data later, you can't pass arrays around in html. indexes and sniffing for smoking guns work.

Comment: Sorry - What do you mean?

Comment: i mean the output is a sting, so you can't have any object references. you need string attribs that guide you back to the data later.

Comment: but that can't be true - because in handlebars you can literally work with objects - like - before the each tags, I could use @index to do various things.

Comment: the problem though is that by the time the onclick event runs, all of the handlebars things have been forgotten by the dumb html. if you can pass an index/key, eg. `populateSecondMenu(@index)`, maybe you can reach the array that way from the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. I have used `arguments`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateSecondMenu(item) {

console.log(arguments);
}
</script>

<div class="entry">
  <h1></h1>
  <div class="body">
     {{#nestedArrays}}
        {{#each this}}
            <div class="listItem" onclick="populateSecondMenu({{this}})">
                <div class="leftSide">
                    <div class="listTitle">Indicator : {{this.length}} </div> 
               </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}         
        {{/nestedArrays}}
  </div>
</div>
```